# Receive value in push button from edit text and pass the value to slider

Tags: matlab, button, rotation, push, edit

I have 3 elements, `Edit Text`, `Push Button` and `Slider`.

In my edit text i have this code:

```
function rotate_edit_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

handles.imgUndo = handles.image;

user_entry = str2double(get(handles.rotate_edit,'string'));
    if isnan(user_entry)
        errordlg('Deve inserir um número','ERRO','modal')
    return
    end

guidata(hObject, handles);
```

In my push button i don't know how i receive a value from edit text and send to slider.

In my slider i have this code:

```
function slider_rotation_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

handles.imgUndo = handles.image;

rotation = str2double(get(handles.rotate_edit,'String'));

imageRot = imrotate( handles.image, rotation, 'crop');
handles.image = imageRot;

imshow(handles.image, 'Parent', handles.axes2);

guidata(hObject, handles);
```

I've tested this without the `Push Button` and the image when round is blurred:(

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem/question??

Comment: In my push button i don't know how i receive a value from edit text and send this value to slider.

Comment: @lion - could you describe how these three controls are supposed to work together?  I understand that the edit text control allows the user to enter an angle of rotation which is then used to rotate your image, but what is the relationship between it and the button?  Should pressing the button force the image to be rotated by x degrees?  Or is that the role of the slider which is to continually apply the rotation as it has been set in the edit text control?

Comment: I decided to not put a push button.

I insert a value in my edit text and when I press ENTER this value passes into my slider, and whenever I move the slider wheel image taking into account the heat that you insert in the edit text.

Only that there is a problem, whenever I play the image gets all blurry.

Code: http://i.imgur.com/l7fWQs7.png

Image with problem: http://i.imgur.com/CJxNrNg.png

Comment: @lion - I think that you may want to edit your question and remove all references to the push button since you have now removed it from your code.  Please be clear as to what the code is doing, what you wish it would be doing, and what the current (undesired) behaviour is.